# waf 1.7: How do you copy an environment?

Tags: waf

I have a waf file that is building several libraries for multiple targets, multiple platforms and, in some cases, multiple architectures.

I currently have the environment set up according to waf 1.7's documents for variants like so:

```
def configure(conf):
   # set up one platform, multiple variants, multiple archs
   for arch in ['x86', 'x86_64']:
      for tgt in ['dbg', 'rel']:
         conf.setenv('platform_' + arch + '_' + tgt)
         conf.load('gcc')   # or some other compiler, such as msvc
         conf.load('gxx')
         #set platform arguments
```

However, this causes waf to output multiple lines searching for the compiler during configure.  It also means that I'm frequently setting up *close* to the same environment multiple times.  I'd like to do this once if possible, for example:

```
def configure(conf):
    # set up platform
    conf.setenv('platform')
    conf.load('gcc')
    conf.load('gxx')
    # set platform arguments
    for arch in ['x86', 'x86_64']:
        for tgt in ['dbg', 'rel']:
            conf.setenv('platform_' + arch + '_' + tgt, conf.env.derive())
            # set specific arguments as needed
```

However, conf.env.derive is a shallow copy, and conf.env.copy() gives me the error **'list' object is not callable**

How is this done in waf 1.7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is to derive from the top architecture, then detach to allow yourself to add more flags to the configuration.  Example:

```
def configure(conf):
    conf.setenv('platform')
    conf.load('gcc')
    conf.load('gxx')
    for arch, tgt in itertools.product(['x86', 'x86_64'],  ['dbg', 'rel']):
        conf.setenv('platform')
        new_env = conf.env.derive()
        new_env.detach()
        conf.setenv('platform_' + arch + '_' + tgt, new_env)
        # Set architecture / target specifics
```